Truth in Heidegger as unconcealment: appearance or appearing?
I would like to understand how to phenomenologically interpret truth as aletheia according to Heidegger. He believes that truth is revealed immediately as "unconcealment."
My question is whether this unconcealment should be understood as the "appearance" of things (= "tools") or as the very act (event) of "coming into presence," that is, the appearing itself of appearance, not as arised but as arising.
A visual example: when I look at a water source, I can focus on the appearance of the water as a fact, or I can focus on the "source" and the very "origin" of the water, paying attention to that line where the water has not yet appeared but is "appearing" right from its origin.
Which of these two views is closer to Heidegger's perspective?
Thanks for the help.

Heidegger’s process-oriented concept of aletheia aka truth as "unconcealment" is closer to the second view you presented: the appearing itSelf of appearance, or the aRising rather than the arisen due to its universal emergent unconcealment as an opening up in which beings can show themselves as they are, who emphasizes the event of coming into presence as ready-to-hand rather than things as they are present-at-hand. In a world that's constantly worlding, truth is the dynamic interplay between concealment and unconcealment which allows beings to be in the first place...

Heidegger subtly changes tac on aletheia (ἀλήθεια) over the years, seemingly from one more in accordance with Aristotle to one with Heidegger's own depth. In 1927 he writes:

"Being-true" ("truth") means Being-uncovering*. But is not this a
highly arbitrary way to define "truth"? By such drastic ways of
defining this concept we may succeed in eliminating the idea of
agreement from the conception of truth. Must we not pay for this
dubious gain by plunging the 'good' old tradition into nullity? But
while our definition is seemingly arbitrary, it contains only the
necessary Interpretation of what was primordially surmised in the oldest tradition of ancient philosophy and even understood in a pre-phenomenological manner. If a λόγος as ἀπόφανσις [apóphansis, assertion] is to be true,
its Being-true is ἀλήθεύειν [unconcealment] in the manner of ἀποφαίνεσθαι [apofaínesthai, appearance]—of taking
entities out of their hiddenness and letting them be seen in their
unhiddenness (their uncoveredness). The ἀλήθεια which Aristotle
equates with πρᾶγμα [prâgma, facts] and φαινόμενα [fainómena, phenomena] in the passages cited above,
signifies the 'things themselves'; it signifies what shows
itself—entities in the "how" of their uncoveredness. Being &
Time, H.
219

In 1964 Heidegger qualifies aletheia as that which enables truth to be.  Truth itself is taken as correspondence and the knowing—"the certainty of the knowledge of Being"—the understanding which beholds a truth.

Insofar as truth is understood in the traditional "natural" sense as
the correspondence of knowledge with beings demonstrated in beings,
but also insofar as truth is interpreted as the certainty of the
knowledge of Being, aletheia, unconcealment in the sense of the
opening may not be equated with truth. Rather, aletheia,
unconcealment thought as opening, first grants the possibility of
truth. For truth itself, just as Being and thinking, can only be what
it is in the element of the opening. Evidence, certainty in every
degree, every kind of verification of veritas already move with
that veritas in the realm of the prevalent opening.
Aletheia, unconcealment thought as the opening of presence, is not yet truth. Is aletheia then less than truth? Or is it more because
it first grants truth as adequatio and certitudo, because there
can be no presence and presenting outside of the realm of the opening?
This question we leave to thinking as a task. Thinking must consider
whether it can even raise this question at all as long as it thinks
philosophically, that is, in the strict sense of metaphysics which
questions what is present only with regard to its presence. On Time
& Being, page
69-70

OP: "My question is whether this unconcealment should be understood as the "appearance" of things (= "tools") or as the very act (event) of "coming into presence," that is, the appearing itself of appearance, not as arised but as arising."
So aletheia is the opening of Being: the clearing in which Dasein can see a thing and comprehend it and ascertain the being-true of the fact that it is in fact, say water.  For example, if one was in a mist, the forming of shapes in the mist would be unconcealment and as a shape takes form and is recognised the assertion, say "it is a boat" constitutes the fact, the truth. Without recognition and assertion the boat is just an unconcealed shape, an unconcealment.  There is no thing at this stage; it is unconditioned, uncomprehended 'presence'.  While understanding can turn the unconcealed into appearance there is no guarantee of truth:

In the midst of beings as a whole an open place comes to presence.
There is a clearing. ... The being [or entity] can only be, as a being, if it
stands within, and stands out within, what is illuminated in this
clearing. Only this clearing grants us human beings access to those
beings that we ourselves are not and admittance  to the being that we
ourselves are. Thanks to this clearing, beings are unconcealed in
certain and changing degrees. But even to be concealed is something
the being can only do within the scope of the illuminated. Each being
which  we encounter and which encounters us maintains this strange
opposition of  presence in that at the same time it always holds
itself back in a concealment. Concealment, however, reigns in the
midst of beings, in a twofold  manner.
Beings refuse themselves to us down to that one and seemingly most
trivial feature which we meet most immediately when all we can say of
a being is that it is. Concealment as refusal is not primarily or only
the  limit of knowledge in each particular case; it is, rather, the
beginning of  the clearing of what is illuminated. But concealment,
though of course of  another sort, also occurs within the illuminated.
Beings push themselves in  front of others, the one hides the other,
this casts that into shadow, a few  obstruct many, on occasion one
denies all. Concealment, here, is not simple  refusal. Rather, a being
indeed appears but presents itself as other than it is. The Origin of the Work of Art, (1935-1936), page 30


I tip my hat; an excellent response. I just have one question: aletheia (= unconcealment) is something prior to classical truth (correspondence) and modern truth (certainty); it is a root that precedes both—understood. What is still unclear to me is that this unconcealment implies "forms" that are still unrecognizable in the mist. You present it almost as a sort of immediately given haecceitas, a "this." I think that if something has already manifested in some way, for Heidegger, those "forms" are not simply chaotic; they already hold some meaning or usefulness for a Dasein.

This is why my question remains: is aletheia those "blurred forms" within the midst that are prior to the "recognition" of a pre-theorical phenomenon (= tool), or is it the very "formation" of those "forms," their very "appearance" prior to "being" a "this"? @Chris Degnen

Hi Ian, the mist and misty forms are just my clumsy metaphor. Unconcealment (for a physical entity) involves raw sensing, comprehension and conditioning to produce the entity as existing for a person. Prior to that it is undiscovered, uncomprehended and unconditioned. In The Origin of the Work of Art Heidegger referred to the place of such things as earth (as in where things are buried). E.g. "Tree, grass, eagle and bull, snake and cricket first enter their distinctive shapes and thus come to appearance as what they are. Early on, the Greeks called this coming forth and rising up in itself

and in all things Φύσις (phúsis, nature). At the same time φύσις lights up that on which man bases his dwelling. We call this the earth. What this word means here is far removed from the idea of a mass of matter and from the merely astronomical idea of a planet. Earth is that in which the arising of everything that arises is brought back – as, indeed, the very thing that it is – and sheltered." (p.21) "The earth is the unforced coming forth of the continually self-closing, and in that way, self-sheltering. World and earth are essentially different and yet never separated from one another.

World is grounded on earth, and earth rises up through world." (p.26) "To the open belongs a world and the earth. But world is not simply the open which corresponds to the clearing, earth is not simply the closed that corresponds to concealment. . . . Earth is not simply the closed but that which rises up as self-closing." (p.31) Hopefully that is a better metaphor.
